# POMM2 in Symfony3 project, trouble with registering converter

Tags: php, postgresql, pomm

The idea is this. In table 'driver' I have fields that describe 'driver', but I need to store another set of fields about 100 which I didn't need to be table columns. So I decided to store them in Jsonb field. I need to be able to work with this fields as model fields, but they need to be automatically saved in one jsonb field.. and when I select from a table I need this field to be shown like other fields from the table.

I have checked documentation about converters and found PgJson converter. So I think that this is the right tool to deal with this problem, but I didn't manage to configure things the right way so far.

I have tried to register field 'testinfo' as type 'extrainfo' which is registered as a converter in SessionBuilder, but have no success. Methods fromPg and toPG are not called. Here I show examples from my project files.

composer.json

```
...
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    ...
    "pomm-project/pomm-bundle": "^2.3",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    ...
    "symfony/symfony": "3.3.6",
    ...
    "vibby/pomm-project-fos-user-bundle": "dev-master"
},
...
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE public.driver
(
  driver_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('driver_driver_id_seq'::regclass),
  account_id integer NOT NULL,
  infodata jsonb, -- large number of fields,...
  weight jsonb, -- weights for fields that are not in jsonb field
  ssn character varying,
  signature character varying
  -- ...
)
```

---

config.yml

```
pomm:
configuration:
    driversdb:
        dsn: "pgsql://%db_user2%:%db_password2%@%db_host2%:%db_port2%/%db_name2%"
        #session_builder: "pomm.session_builder"
        pomm:default: true
        session_builder: 'AppBundle\Model\Driversdb\SessionBuilder'
```

---

services.yml

```
...
drivertojson:
    class: AppBundle\Service\DriverToJson
    tags:
        - { name: pomm.model, converter: pomm.model }

AppBundle\Model\Driversdb\SessionBuilder:
    autowire: true
...
```

---

/src/AppBundle/Model/Driversdb/SessionBuilder.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Model\Driversdb;

use AppBundle\Service\DriverToJson;          //Exact Copy of Pomm PgJson converter.
use PommProject\Foundation\Converter\PgJson;
use PommProject\Foundation\Session\Session;
use PommProject\ModelManager\SessionBuilder as BaseSessionBuilder;

class SessionBuilder extends BaseSessionBuilder
{
    protected function postConfigure(Session $session) {
        parent::postConfigure($session);

        $session
            ->getPoolerForType('converter')
            ->getConverterHolder()
            ->registerConverter('extrainfo', new DriverToJson(), ['infodata', 'public.driver.infodata']) // register Jsonb converter
            ->addTypeToConverter('extrainfo', 'extrainfo', false) // convert a domain of point
        ;
    }
}
```

---

/src/AppBundle/Model/Driversdb/PublicSchema/Driver.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Model\Driversdb\PublicSchema;

use PommProject\ModelManager\Model\FlexibleEntity;

/**
 * Driver
 * Flexible entity for relation
 * public.driver
 * @see FlexibleEntity
*/
class Driver extends FlexibleEntity
{
    public $keyForId = 'driver_id';

    public function getId() {
        return $this->get($this->keyForId);
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->getSsn();
    }

    private $driver_id;
    private $account_id;
    private $infodata;
    private $weight;
    private $ssn;
    private $signature;
    //...
    private $testinfo;

    public function getTestinfo() {
        if ($this->has('testinfo')) {
            return $this->get('testinfo');
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }

    public function getDriverId() {
        if ($this->has('driver_id')) {
            return $this->get('driver_id');
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }

    public function getAccountId() {
        if ($this->has('account_id')) {
            return $this->get('account_id');
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
//...
```

---

/src/Appbundle/Controller/DriverController.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Form\DriverFormType;
use AppBundle\Model\Driversdb\PublicSchema\Driver;
use AppBundle\Model\Driversdb\PublicSchema\DriverModel;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use AppBundle\Service\DriverToJson;

class DriverController extends Controller
{
//...
/**
     * @Route("/driver", name="driver_create")
     * @Method ("POST")
     * @Template("@App/Driver/new.html.twig")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request){
        $driver = new Driver();
        $form = $this->createForm(DriverFormType::class, $driver,[
            'action'=> $this->generateUrl('driver_create'),
            'method'=> 'POST'
        ]);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isValid()){
            $driver = $form->getData();
            try{
                /** @var DriverModel $driverModel */
                $driverModel = $this->get('pomm')['driversdb']->getModel(DriverModel::class);
                $driverModel->insertOne($driver);
                return $this->redirectToRoute('driver_list');
            }catch (\Exception $e){
                throw $e;
            }
        }
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid form data');
    }
//...
}
```

---

/src/AppBundle/Form/DriverFormType.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Model\Driversdb\PublicSchema\Driver;
use AppBundle\Service\DriverToJson;
use PommProject\Foundation\Converter\ConverterPooler;
use PommProject\PommBundle\Request\ParamConverter\EntityParamConverter;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class DriverFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $builder
            ->add('testinfo', 'extrainfo', array('mapped'=>false))
            ->add('account_id', TextType::class)
            ->add('ssn', TextType::class,array(
                'attr'  => [
                    'class' => 'col-xs-12'
                ]
            ))
           // ... many other fields.
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class'=> Driver::class,
            'attr'=>array('novalidate'=>'novalidate'),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you configure your session builder in your application configuration?
https://github.com/pomm-project/pomm-bundle/blob/master/tests/app/config/config.yml#L38

Comment: Yes I have set Session builder in config.yml.

Comment: Your table definition of the `infodata` field is type `jsonb` not `extrainfo`. This might be why the converter is never triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pomm’s converter use the field type to determine wich converter it should be call. Your field should be a `extrainfo`.

Create this new type:

```sql
CREATE DOMAIN extrainfo AS jsonb;
```

And use it for the `infodata` column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE driver ALTER COLUMN infodata TYPE extrainfo;
```

Comment: Maybe `CREATE DOMAIN` instead of `CREATE TYPE` ?